# How to extract only the required portion of a line in shell script?

Tags: unix, search, required

In a shell script of a line I have a pattern like

`a=1;
b=2; 
c = 3;
d =4`

I used sed `-n -e 's/.*a=//p'` filename which is giving the entire line but I need it as a result with values `a=1 b=2`

I need the value of a and b. How can I extract them?

Comment: Please show a minimum effort that you have tried.

Comment: I used sed -n -e 's/.*a=//p' filename which is giving the entire line but I need it as a result with values a=1 b=2

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542927/how-to-handle-a-file-using-key-value-pair-in-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

You can user the command like --> 
cat filename |tr ' ' '\n'|egrep 'a|b'
This command will work if you need to extract only a or b.